# xsl-fo for-each loop

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I need some way to create FO file in which tables are created for-each loop

Are there any way?

Comment: Without input sample and desired output this is not a real question.

Comment: Alejandro, I need to create tables, as content of tables, may be anything , for example "text1", "text2"

Answer (score 0):

The example at [w3schools.com XSLT Transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) should give you an idea. Here is an excerpt:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```